# Selecting from table where value update other table value Codeigniter problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am having some problems with my CodeIgniter website I am trying to select a value from the table 'orders' column 'custom' if this email address matches the user's email address who is currently logged it will need to set the `'donater'` in the `'users' table to 1`. But I get an error message. I have very little coding experience this is what I came up with:

```
public function hasDonated($email){
$this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->where('custom', $email);
    $this->db->update('users', array('donater' => '1'));
    return;
}
```

This is the error I get it tries to select `'custom'` in the `users` table but it needs to be selected from the 'orders' table what aI i doing wrong?

```
Unknown column 'custom' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `users` SET `donater` = '1' WHERE `custom` = 'testing@test.com'
```

Comment: Please check `custom` is available in `orders` table.

Comment: it is but i think the script is looking for custom in the users table so i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Can you list out `users` table's fields here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
public function hasDonated($email){
$resp = $this->db->select('custom')->from('orders')->where('custom',$email)->get();
    if( $resp->num_rows() > 0 ) {   
    $this->db->set('donater', 1);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->update('users');
  }
  return;
}
```